# How do i Upload a file using serenity screenplay pattern

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

I'm working on serenity screenplay pattern.

I need to upload a file to a textbox on a webpage but I got the following error:

> "TargettedAction invalid element state: Element must be user-editable
>   in order to clear it."

This is where I am getting the error in my code :

```
public const string Filepath = "C:\\Series_GRPAAA_ver1.xsls"

When(_actor).AttemptsTo(Enter.TheText(Filepath).Into(HomePage.BulkUploadFilename()));
```

Comment: HomePage.BulkUploadFilename() is the static method that returns the webelement which is a textbox. and its defined as.                                                                                                                
 public static ITarget BulkUploadFilename()
        {
            return new ElementId("bulkUploadFileName", "BulkUploadFilename");

        }

Comment: I discover that the element has readonly attribute. below is the html.                       <input type="text" readonly="" class="upload-series-filename-control" id="bulkUploadFileName">